# Not able to pass checked checkbox value to next php page with ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a code in which i want to send the checked checkbpxes values to next php page with ajax call.But i am not able to send pass it properly.Previously i asked similar question some time back.

Following is the code

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Insert title here</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function get_check_value() {
        var c_value = [];
        $('input[name="services"]:checked').each(function () {
            c_value.push(this.value);
        });
        //return c_value.join(',');
    }
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#btnSubmit').on('click', function () {
            alert("hi");
            //var os = $('#originState').val();
            //var c = $('#commodity').val();
            //var ds = $('#destState').val();
            var ser = get_check_value();
            //var queryString = "os=" + os;
            var queryString = "&ser=" + ser;
            $.ajax({
           type: "GET",
       url:'sortingajax.php',
       data:"queryString="+querystring,
               success:function(data){
            alert(data);
                console.log(data);
                    $('#results').html(data);
               }
            });

        });
    });
</script>
<form name="searchForm">
    <input type="checkbox" name="services" value="twic" />TWIC
    <br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="services" value="enclosedTrucking" />Enclosed Trucking
    <br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="services" value="flatBedTrucking" />Flat Bed Trucking
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" value="Submit" />
</form>
<div id="results">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

ajaxcall.php

```
    <?php

        include('connection.php');
$query=$_GET['querystring'];
echo $query;
        $countsql='SELECT * FROM table1 ';
        $countsql1=mysql_query($countsql);
        $numrows = mysql_num_rows($countsql1);  
        $countArray2=array();

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($countsql1)) {
            // Append to the array
            $Array2[] = $row;
        }
    ?>
    <?php
        foreach($Array2 as $array)
        {
    ?>
    <div class="search">hi</div>

    <?php 
            $i++; 
        }
    ?>
```

I am not able to get the content now with ajaxcall html content.but i m unable to do that..
Please guide me guyzzz

Comment: You know you can't send something to the next page, then redirect to the next page and it's magically there, right ?

Comment: Try un-commenting this `//return c_value.join(',');` statement. Also when you run a PHP script via ajax, it can perform a function(s) for you and return results, but it does not have a visible page. Think of it more like running a function or subroutine. You are not redirecting to it, you are asking it to do some work for you but it does not throw a page to the user. So if you want to see what it is doing, you need a debugger or write the results to a file and look at that to see the debug statements you are currently trying to output to the browser.

Comment: I tried un-commenting the line.but still ajaxcall.php html content not getting replaced in results div

Comment: There is no meaning in making post request with no request parameters, and the target php not containing even single $_POST variable to handle the request.

Comment: correct the spell of success function.

Comment: @PrakashGPz-I tried passing parameters with ajax and getting it in next php page,but still i m not replace the div content sir.please help.updating the code.

Comment: @VipinSoni-I corrected the spellings,but still not able to get the data from ajax call

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand what you are trying to achieve, you could add hidden input to your form and pass is value, your script would set it to hidden control.

```
<form name="searchForm">
<input type="hidden" id="checkboxCollection">
<input type="checkbox" name="services" value="twic" />TWIC
<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="services" value="enclosedTrucking" />Enclosed Trucking
<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="services" value="flatBedTrucking" />Flat Bed Trucking
<br/>
<input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

then script would change to

```
 function get_check_value() {
    var c_value = [];
    $('input[name="services"]:checked').each(function () {
        c_value.push(this.value);
    });

$('#checkboxCollection').val(c_value.join(','));
    //return c_value.join(',');
}
```

and then read the checkboxCollection when you submit the form.

Comment: I am not able to display ajaxcall.php content in results div after ajax call sir actually